# Django - Specifying default attr for Custom widget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I have created this widget

```
class DateTimeWidget(forms.TextInput):
  attr = {'class': 'datetimepicker'}
  class Media:
    js = ('js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js',)
```

Then I use it on my form

```
class SessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Session
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SessionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['start_time'].widget = DateTimeWidget()
    self.fields['end_time'].widget = DateTimeWidget()
```

No css `class` is applied to my fields (I'm expecting *datetimepicker* applied to both `start_time` & `end_time`).
I imagine I have put `attr` at a wrong location. Where am I supposed to specify it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see multiple problems:

- To override the attrs, you need to override the init and update the attrs. Or you could give attrs when initializing the widget. see: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L163
- widgets can also be defined like:

.

```
class SessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Session
        widgets = {'start_time': DateTimeWidget(),
                   'end_time': DateTimeWidget()}
```

Comment: +1 using the `Meta.widgets` attribute makes the `SessionForm` a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I was searching for. The override technique seems good. And thank you for the widget property.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, the html attributes are stored in `widget.attrs`, not `attr`.

Secondly, you can't declare `attrs = {'class': 'datetimepicker'}` in your widget definition, because the `__init__` method will overwrite `self.attrs`.

Instead, you can set the `attrs` in the `__init__` method.

Here's a rather naive implementation.  You might want to add some extra checks to make sure you don't overwrite any existing items in `kwargs['attrs']`. Note that we have subclassed `DateTimeInput` instead of `TextInput`.

```
class DateTimeWidget(DateTimeInput):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['attrs'] = {'class': 'datepicker'}
        super(DatePickerWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that attr were more linked to the widget than the form field. Why subclassing `DateTimeInput` instead of `TextInput` ?

Comment: You don't have to subclass `DateTimeInput`, but you might find its date formatting functionality useful.